# Cannot connect to wifi with wpa_supplicant

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, root, wpa-supplicant, wpa

I just installed Arch Linux on my laptop. So far I have only been able to connect to wired networks. When I try to connect to my wifi network with `wpa_supplicant -D nl80211,wext -i wlp3s0 -C <(wpa_passphrase "SKYNET-5GHz" < password.txt)` I get this error:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Could not unlink existing ctrl_iface socket '/dev/fd/63/wlp3s0': Not a directory
Failed to initialize control interface '/dev/fd/63'.
You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was
left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need
to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.

nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp3s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
```

I did some reading and found this:

> Note: Because of the process substitution, you cannot run this command with sudo - you will need a root shell. Just pre-pending sudo will lead to the following error:
>   Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
>   Failed to open config file '/dev/fd/63', error: No such file or directory
>   Failed to read or parse configuration '/dev/fd/63'

[WPA supplicant - Connecting with wpa_passphrase | wiki.archlinux.org](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/WPA_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_passphrase)

That says I need to be in a root shell rather than running with the `sudo` prefix. The thing is, that's what I have been doing. I have tried this by logging into my computer as root and as logging in with my user and switching to root with `su - root`, but I always get this error.

Comment: Can you just... remove the thing, reboot and try again?

Comment: Have you checked if there is a second instance of `wpa_supplicant` running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [wiki.archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Automatic_setup) You can use one connection manager because:

> you should not run two daemons simultaneously

`netctl` is installed by default, i think you are using a GUI like Network-manager.

Remove netctl and Network-manager

Reinstall Network-Manager

Try to connect through `wpa_supplicant`

Comment: I will try that later and let you know how it goes. I have my other ssd in right now.